# Validation Rules on Fields

Tags: validation

I am have started learning Salesforce.
Can anyone please help me in validation Rules, I tried but I am failed in this.

Scenario: I have DataType (Percent) field called Score, when it is not blank automatically the other fields that the date field should be today's date and the Complete field should be automatically checked.

I have 2 scenarios like this, but I need it in a single Validation Rule.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please learn the basics in Salesforce trailhead, validation rule as name suggests simply validates the data as per rule.

Comment: You can't update a SFDC field or a picklist filed with a VR.You can only validate/Check with validation rules.

Comment: you can use a work flow or the process builder to check on criteria and then fill in certain fields when that criteria is met. Not validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a SFDC field or a picklist filed with a VR.You can only validate/Check with validation rules.
Take the below example .It will only check  Your_Lookup__c is blank and Your_Picklist__c is not blank

```
 AND(
  ISBLANK(Your_Lookup__c),
  NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Your_Picklist__c)))
```

)